# NSDictionary - need to obtain value for key subelement

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value-coding

I have created an NSDictionary named "myData"
which contains the following JSON response:

```
{
listInfo =     (              
{ 
    date = 1392157366000;       
    dateAsString = "02/11/2014 22:22:46";     
    id = 6;  
    address = 542160e0000c;     
    myLevel = 13;  
},            
{

    date = 1392155568000;        
    dateAsString = "02/11/2014 21:52:48";      
    id = 5;    
    address = 542160e0000c;     
    myLevel = 13;

}
    );
}
```

I need to retrieve each of the [dateAsString] key/value pairs.
I've tried:  NSString *dateAsString=[[myData valueForKeyPath:@"dateAsString"][0] objectForKey:@"myData"]; without any luck.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  Then ***look*** at what you have.  You erroneously omitted the leading `{` in the dump indicating the start of a dictionary.  The only element in the dictionary is "listInfo".  The value of that element is an NSArray (as indicated by the `()` brackets), and that array contains 2 dictionaries (bracketed by `{}`).  If you take it one step at a time it's incredibly easy to take that apart and extract the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

`NSArray* dateStringArray = [listInfo valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.dateAsString"]`

I believe it will give you an array of strings.  If you need to stuff that back in a dictionary, that should be fairly easy.

It's not clear what your "myData" looks like... so I used the listInfo array of dicts shown.

Comment: I think "listInfo" is the first and only key in an outer dictionary, so it would be something like `[myData valueForKeyPath:@"listInfo.dateAsString"]`.

Comment: Actually, `[myData valueForKeyPath:@"listInfo.@unionOfObjects.dateAsString"]` if that is the case

Comment: @stevesliva - Thanks for your response. Actually, the "myData" dictionary contains the listInfo dictionary.

Comment: @Chuck - Thanks Chuck, this is the solution I will use.

Comment: All you wanted was a path to a single element?!

Comment: Which incidentally would be `myData[@"listInfo][0][@"dateAsString"]`  Using @unionOfObjects in the keyPath gives you an array for the middle [0]